# Device Administration App & AppData Wipe on Android

Tags: java, android, root-access, device-policy-manager

I'm working on a [Device Administration App](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) for Android Tablets, that will enable Advanced Account Management on Honeycomb/ICS devices.

One crucial feature of this application is the ability to wipe all applications data when a new user logs in : the preinstalled apps should be cleaned up and offer first-launch experience to the new user.

So, I'm looking for a way to clean all applications data (inner settings, user data...) on a device from this administration app. I've seen that such apps can perform data wipe with the [wipeData](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#wipeData%28int%29) method but I'm afraid this will only do a factory reset which is not what I'm looking for : system settings should not be altered, and installed applications should not be erased.

Do you guys have any idea where to look for such a feature ?

I will consider any tips, even ones that requires Root access on the device, if any...

Thanks.